# How to facilitate meetings / events with participant registration, agenda and documents?

Tags: 7

How to manage meetings in Drupal? I would like to do the following:

- Participants can register for an event or be added by the admin.
- The meeting has an agenda, consisting of a number of agenda points.
- Documents can be attached to the various agenda points.
- Participant details, the agenda and documents are shown.
- Record that the meeting is one in a series of meetings of the same group.

An example of what is needed is [here](http://www.iode.org/index.php?option=com_oe&task=viewEventDocs&eventID=1120), but the site is Joomla and it seems to be a custom module.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a feature to implement for which just a short description and a off-site link is given.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options in Drupal allowing you to add registrations to content. So if you add a content type of 'meeting', you can add file fields, dates and an agenda text field. Add a taxonomy field for grouping by type.

Then with any of the registration modules you can register users.

- [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration)
- [Node registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_registration)
- [RNG](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng) (Drupal 8)

Basically it is not one module, but a combination of fields and modules to get the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a distribution

Have a look at [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium). Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> A new architecture for Drupal 7 that is built upon [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) and [Panopoly](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly) and intended as an extensible collaboration framework. Adds the ability to have private "sections" within a collaboration space with granular access control. Drag/drop layout control with dozens of widgets that can be placed on dashboards and landing pages. Comes with Discussions, Events, Files, Issue tracking, and Document Wiki out of the box, along with the dashboards to manage it all.

## Use modules that fit your needs

If you'd rather want to roll your own cookies, then there are quite some contributed modules that should help to get you going. Refer to my answers to these questions for more details:

- [How to implement RSVP Functionality?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167709/how-to-implement-rsvp-functionality/167714#167714)
- [How to limit access to a meeting content type to only the participants specified via Entity Reference?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169314/how-to-limit-access-to-a-meeting-content-type-to-only-the-participants-specified)